# Работа с кешем в WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

WebView сохраняет в кэш страницу и по возможности не загружает её, а берёт именно оттуда. Что будет. если изменится контент на странице? Проверяет ли webview как-то актуальность кешированой страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При нормальной загрузке страницы, кэш проверяется и обновляется при необходимости.
В других случаях (например, при навигации назад) за это отвечает метод *void setCacheMode (int mode)*, атрибут которого по умолчанию - LOAD_DEFAULT (содержимое берётся из кэша, если он доступен и не истёк, иначе - загружается)

Другие атрибуты этого метода:

**LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK** - использование даже истёкшего кэша

**LOAD_NO_CACHE** - кэш не используется

**LOAD_CACHE_ONLY** - без сети, только кэш

Comment: "кэш проверяется и обновляется при необходимости". Т.е. webview гарантирует, что контент страницы, при наличии интернета у меня всегда актуален?)

Comment: @ManGust [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setCacheMode(int)] For a normal page load, the cache is checked and content is re-validated as needed - cудя по документации, да